# How can I change numbers to a letter in a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to change numbers in a string to an assigned letter (0 would be 'A', 1 => 'B' and so on...).

In this case I must use a function (def) to change the numbers to the assigned letter. I tried doing the program with if's in a for cycle with indices and it worked, but apperantly there is an easier and shorter solution. I tried doing it with isdigit() instead, but my function doesn't recognize the numbers in the given word and just prints out the same word

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ?

Comment: What happens to multidigit sequencees like "a11b22"?

Comment: `"a1b2c3".translate(str.maketrans("0123456789", "ABCDEFGHIJ"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to map digits to letters, write a generator to get those letters and join it all into a resultant string. The dictionary's `get` method either gets the value or returns a default. Use this to return any non-digit characters.

```
>>> digit_map = dict(zip('123456789', 'ABCDEFGHI'))
>>> test = 'a1b2c3'
>>> "".join(digit_map.get(c,c) for c in test)
'aAbBcC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that you can use to convert numbers to letters in a given string:

```
def convert_numbers_to_letters(s):
    # Create a dictionary that maps numbers to letters
    number_to_letter = {str(i): chr(i + ord('A')) for i in range(10)}

    # Iterate through each character in the string
    result = ""
    for c in s:
        # If the character is a number, convert it to a letter
        if c.isdigit():
            result += number_to_letter[c]
        # Otherwise, just add the character to the result
        else:
            result += c

    return result
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord` to get the numeric value of a character, and `chr` to turn the numeric value back into a character.  That lets you convert a number like `1` into its offset from another character.

Then use `join` to put it all together:

```
>>> ''.join(chr(int(c)+ord('A')) if c.isdecimal() else c for c in 'a1b2c3')
'aBbCcD'
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be creating an array that would store each letter as a string as such:

```py
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C"] // and so on
```

Then you could loop trough the string and find all numbers, then for each numbers get the corresponding letter by accessing it from the array as such `py alphabet[i]` and feed it back to the string and return that